# Why this LINQ throws NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

```
private SmtpClient getServer()
        {
            return (from e in doc.Elements("emailsetting")
                    select new SmtpClient()
                    {
                        Host = e.Attribute("server").Value,
                        Port = Convert.ToInt32(e.Attribute("port").Value)
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

The xml config file:

```
  <emailsetting>
    <stmp server="10.182.182.182" port="25" />
    <from address="ithelpdest@citics.com.hk"/>
    <to address=""/>
    <cc address=""/>
  </emailsetting>
```

Why throws the exception:
NullReferenceException was unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm new to LINQ,plz help.

Comment: 'smtp' is spelled as 'stmp' in the XML. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing only the `emailsetting` element, which doesn't have an attribute named `server` or `port`.
You need to get the attributes from the `smtp` child element.

Try this:

```
return (from e in doc.Elements("emailsetting")
        let smtp = e.Element("smtp")
        select new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = smtp.Attribute("server").Value,
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtp.Attribute("port").Value)
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1, but just take care of typos : OP's has wrong "stmp" instead of "smtp" in xml sample

Comment: Thank you. But does the LINQ returns a object? cause when I call Console.WriteLine(getServer().Host) to test the ip, it throws the same exception

Comment: @user838204 have you taken into account the typo in your xml? you have written "stmp" instead of "smtp". So you should to change your xml to use "smtp". also, is doc possibly null?

Comment: I notice the typo and change it to smtp. And doc can't be null. I try SmtpClient smtp = getServer(); and find smtp=null

Comment: I used this: from e in doc.element("smtp") rather than from e in doc.Elements("emailsetting")
        let smtp = e.Element("smtp")